# Can I increment SDL_Surface refcount myself

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2. I'd like to keep track of my codes references of the SDL_Surface that I'll be passing around.

My question is if it's safe to use `++surface->refcount` on my own.

More broadly, will that be safe for all SDL structs which have a ref count?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) says you can increment it. To decrement refcount, use `SDL_FreeSurface`.

The same goes for every other refcount SDL exposes - increment it yourself, but use corresponding `Free` function to decrement.